# Structure apex class with several if else clauses

Tags: apex

I got an apex class that checks orders and for each `country` on the Order record, we need to perform unique actions - there are currently 10 countries and I wish to avoid doing something like

```
if (order.Status != 'In Progress' && order.StartDate != null && order.Country__c == 'SE') {
  // specific action for "SE" orders
}
else if (order.Status != 'In Progress' && order.SomeOtherAction != null && order.Country__c == 'DE') {
  // specific action for "DE" orders

}
else if (order.Status != 'Cancelled' && order.SomeOtherDateField != null && order.Country__c == 'FR') {
  // specific action for "FR" orders
  // eg create a case
}
else if (order.Status != 'Completed' && order.StartDate != null && order.Country__c == 'DK') {
  // specific action for "DK" orders
  // eg create a case and update a field value on order
}
else if (order.Status != 'In Progress' && order.StartDate != null && order.Country__c == 'ES') {
  // specific action for "ES" orders

}
else if (order.Status != 'In Progress' && order.StartDate != null && order.Country__c == 'BE') {
  // specific action for "BE" orders
}
...
```

You get the point - it gets super messy really quick. Is Polymorphism my solution here? Should I create some form of base class? Not sure what solution I'm looking for - I just don't wanna have these type of else if clauses - and for some countries there are even some nested logic that needs to take place, e.g if `order.Country == 'SE' && order.SomeStatus = 'Value A' -> do X`, else if `order.Country == 'SE' && order.SomeStatus = 'Value B' -> do Y`

Answer (score 1):

Complexity like this is pretty hard to reduce. I think you'll find that you can shuffle things around, but you'll still end up with code that mimics this giant if/else if/else chain (be it with an if/else if chain, child/inner classes, etc...)

I think there's still value in trying to shuffle things around though. Breaking things up into smaller classes can help in isolating changes (which should mean there's a lower risk of breaking other things when you make a change to a single part).

I think that the "best practice" approach here is probably going to involve a map, a base class, and child classes. For sake of example, let's just put everything into a single class.

```java
public class MyClass{
    // This abstract class acts like a contract.
    // For everything that extends it, we know that it must have a doWork() method
    //   that takes an Order and returns void
    // This will help us a bit later
    public abstract class OrderHandler{
        public abstract void doWork(Order ord);
    }

    // The main thing we care about is which country the order is for.
    // You'll create one child class per country, and encapsulate the specific logic
    //   for that country so that the "clients" of this class can focus on
    //   their own work
    public class DEOrderHandler extends OrderHandler{
        public override void doWork(Order ord){
            // This is a demonstration of the "fail/exit early" approach
            // Weed out things that we don't/can't work on first
            if(ord.Status == 'In Progress' || String.isNotBlank(ord.OtherAction__c)){
                return;
            }

            // Special sub-conditions are also handled here in the child class
            if(ord.SomeStatus == 'Value 1'){
                // do work 1
            }else{
                // do work 2
                Case deOrderCase = new Case(...);
            }
        }

    // Maps can often be used to replace if/else chains, but it doesn't really
    //   reduce complexity (or typing for that matter)
    // Here's why it was important to make that Base class
    // It allows us to put different child classes in a single map, allowing us to 
    //   easily (and relatively compactly) select which code path we want to execute
    private Map<String, OrderHandler> handlerMap = new Map<String, OrderHandler>{
        'SE' => new SEOrderHandler(),
        'DE' => new DEOrderHandler(),
        ...
        'BE' => new BEOrderHandler()
    }

    // Let's say that this method is where you would see the giant if/else chain
    //   in the naive approach
    public void mainMethod(){
        // other code

        // Instead of a giant if/else chain, we can now use the map defined above.
        // While I think the overall complexity is the same, and we may have even
        //   forced ourselves into doing _more_ typing than the if/else chain, one of
        //   the big gains here is that we now do not need to touch _this_ particular
        //   code if we want to add/remove a country or change what work gets done
        //   for a particular country
        for(Order o :ordersList){
            OrderHandler handler = handlerMap.get(o.Country);

            if(handler == null){
                continue;
            }

            // Since every sub-class is a child of OrderHandler (and we're working
            //   as if handler were just an OrderHandler), we don't need any special
            //   logic here.
            // Just call doWork() and pass it the order.
            // The magic of objects and inheritance ensures we perform the correct work
            //   for the country.
            handler.doWork(o);
        }

        // more code
    }
}
```

For a few minutes, I was thinking that you'd need to use an SObject as a "composite key" of sorts. I don't think you need to use that here, but it is a nifty extension to the concept above to keep in mind.

In a nutshell, we toss out the common advice of "don't use SObjects in Sets or as the key of a Map" and turn a Map into a blisteringly fast way to compare multiple fields on an SObject.

As a simple example

```java
Map<SObject, Integer> sObjToIntMap = new Map<SObject, Integer>{
    // Two very important things for this approach:
    //   1) Do not modify the SObject instance used for the key AT ALL. Use SObject's
    //     .clone() method to get a new instance if you need to
    //   2) The object instance used as a map key should not have its Id field populated
    new Account(
        RecordType = new RecordType(Name = 'Account Type 1'),
        My_Status__c = 'Active',
        // Having relationship fields populated with Ids is fine
        ParentId = '001000000000001AAA'
    ) => 1,
    new Account(
        RecordType = new RecordType(Name = 'Account Type 1'),
        My_Status__c = 'Inactive',
        // Having relationship fields populated with Ids is fine
        ParentId = '001000000000002AAA'
    ) => 2
};

for(Account a :[SELECT Id, My_Status__c, RecordType.Name, ParentId FROM Account LIMIT 100]){
    // When you want to compare an SObject to your map, you may be able to get 
    //   away with a simple .clone() to get rid of the Id
    // Constructing a new instance may be safer
    Account targetKey = new Account(
        // The order in which you specify fields shouldn't matter
        My_Status__c = a.My_Status__c,
        ParentId = a.Parent_Id__c,
        RecordType = a.RecordType
    );

    Integer result = sObjToIntMap.get(targetKey);
    system.debug(result);
}
```